# How to style grid cells in vaadin

Tags: java, html, css, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I have created a simple grid with one column:

```
public MyGrid() {
    addComponentColumn(this::getIcon).setClassNameGenerator(i -> "icon-img");
    setItems(/** some items */);
    setClassName("sidebar-grid");
}
```

And I have a css theme called `mangaTheme`. I use it like this `@Theme("mangaTheme")`. In the  mangaTheme folder I have `styles.css` file with the following content:

```
.icon-img {
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-grid {
    width: 102px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: -30%;
}
```

The `sidebar-grid` css properties are applied properly as the grid is moved, but the `icon-img` properties are not applied whatsoever:[image]

The classnames are applied: [image]

What am I doing wrong or missing? I have also read this guide: https://cookbook.vaadin.com/dynamic-grid-cell-styling

EDIT: After configuring my workspace as was mentioned in the answer this is the resulting structure, but it still does not seem to function properly.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is that the cell `<td>` element is inside the shadow DOM of the `vaadin-grid` component, and thus cannot be styled with global CSS. To style parts of components that are inside the component's shadow DOM, you need to inject the CSS into the component.

In the Cookbook example, this is done through the `themeFor` parameter in the annotation that loads the stylesheet:

```
@CssImport(themeFor = "vaadin-grid", value = "./recipe/dynamicgridcellstyling/dynamic-grid-cell-styling.css")
```

In your theme folder, however, you can do the same thing by putting that CSS in a stylesheet called vaadin-grid.css in the `components` subfolder, i.e.:

```
themes/mangaTheme/components/vaadin-grid.css
```

Another thing you're missing is that the classname is applied to the `<td>` cell, but the padding is on the `vaadin-grid-cell-content` element slotted into the cell, not the cell itself, so you need to rewrite your selector:

```
.icon-img ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content) {
    padding: 0;
}
```

(The sidebar-grid CSS class works fine as-is because it's applied to the vaadin-grid root element, which is in the page's regular DOM.)

Comment: I have set it up according to your comment but it doesn't seem to work, I have updated the post in the edit.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one part of the solution. I've now updated my answer to include it.

Comment: This also does not work, but it works if you put a space between: `.icon-img ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content)`. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Ah, sorry again, typo, fixed now in the answer. Glad you got it working! (And remember to mark the answer as accepted so others can see it worked :) )