# How to add ellipsis end of long text in vaadin's gridPro cell?

Tags: java, css, web-applications, vaadin

Ellipsis added end of long string in vaadin's gridPro

[image]

I want to add ellipsis end of long texts which are longer than vaadin's gridPro cells. I am using vaadin 19.8.4 version. I am newbie with css and vaadin.

I have created css file and tried to use it with `setId()` after `grid.addColumn()`  but none of them worked.

I have use chatGpt and it suggest me a lot of ways but none of them too did not worked.

Some of these solutions only changed appearance of column's name, not content.

I've also tried `` and `setCellStyleGenerator()` methods but my vaadin didn't recognize these methods.

I have tried  below code snippets separately:

```
    grid.addColumn().setFlexGrow(1).getElement()
            .getStyle()
            .set("max-width", "100px")
            .set("overflow", "hidden")
            .set("text-overflow", "ellipsis")
            .set("white-space", "nowrap");



    grid.getElement().executeJs("$0.getElementsByClassName('your-column')[0].style.setProperty('max-width', '100px')",
            grid.getElement().getNode());
    grid.getElement().executeJs("$0.getElementsByClassName('your-column')[0].style.setProperty('text-overflow', 'ellipsis')",
            grid.getElement().getNode());
    grid.getElement().executeJs("$0.getElementsByClassName('your-column')[0].style.setProperty('white-space', 'nowrap')",
            grid.getElement().getNode());    

.setStyleGenerator()
```

Comment: Sidenote: Vaadin 19 is no longer maintained, the maintained branch is Vaadin 23, so I would consider upgrading to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style grid cells in vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452065/how-to-style-grid-cells-in-vaadin)