Set padding-left for cells on first column
I would like to set the padding of the cells in the first columns.
I tried it like descriphttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452065/how-to-style-grid-cells-in-vaadin but i does not work.
I have a component that contains a grid. The css import at the component looks like this:
@CssImport(themeFor = "vaadin-grid", value = "./vaadin-grid.css")
public class MyComponent extends AbstractCompositeField<Component,....

The vaadin-grid.css file looks like this:
.vaadin-grid ::part(first-column-cell) {
  padding-left: 0;
}

Tried to use the selectors that are described here
Style Grid but it does not work. The configured padding is not used in the cells. Vaadin 24 is used.
How does the selector has to look like that only the cells of the first column is modified?

Please revise and edit your content (including the title) to show that you have put in the time to compose the question; otherwise it will lead to downvotes and neglect.
Also avoid pasting url links as is and instead use hyperlinks via the [] & ()  symbols.
Cheers

What "does not work" - the CSS, the aligning of only one column?  You
link to docs, that look promising, but your CSS is different from the
docs.  And for good measure please also add the Flow version you are
using -- there where changes on how things are styled in the not so
distant past.

@cfrick The selector defined in the caadin-grid.css is not working. padding does not change.
